# How to find a subspace gives maximum angle between two vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

If there are two vectors in 3-d space, how to find a subspace gives maximum angle between two vectors after projection? Assume we only consider angles between 0-90 degree and the projection happens on the first quadrant.

My answer is I can always find a subspace that the maximum angle after projection is 90 degree unless these two vectors are are completely overlapped with each other?

Comment: Correct, if the vectors are not parallel, then there is a projection where the projected results will be perpendicular.

Comment: Thanks. Another question is can we find that subspace which gives the 90 degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the second question: "can we find the subspace which gives the 90-degree [separation]?"

I  think this should work (for non-parallel vectors):

Let $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ be your vectors, using $A$ and $B$ (without over-arrows) as their lengths.  Define a basis as:

$$
\begin{align}
\hat x &= {\vec A \over A}\\
\hat z &= {\vec A \times \vec B \over |\vec A \times \vec B|}\\
\hat y&= \hat z \times \hat x
\end{align}
$$
This is an orthonormal basis, with $\vec A$ on the positive $x$-axis and $\vec B$ in the $xy$ plane.  Let $\theta$ be the angle between $\vec A$ and $\vec B$.  We have:
$$
\begin{align}
\vec A &= A \hat x\\
\vec B &= B \cos \theta \hat x + B \sin \theta \hat y
\end{align}
$$

Rotate around the $x$-axis by angle $\phi$ ($-\pi/2 < \phi < \pi/2$, $\phi \neq 0$) to get:
$$
\begin{align}
\vec A' &= A \hat x = \vec A \\
\vec B' &= B \cos \theta \hat x + B \sin \theta \cos \phi \hat y + B \sin \theta \sin \phi \hat z
\end{align}
$$

The vector $\vec B'$ casts a "shadow" onto the $xz$ plane at
$$
\vec {P'} = B \cos \theta \hat x + B \sin \theta \sin \phi \hat z
$$
Rotate $\vec {P'}$ around the $x$-axis by angle -$\phi$ to get:

$$
\vec P = B \cos \theta \hat x + B \sin \theta \sin^2 \phi \hat y +
B \sin \theta \sin \phi \cos \phi \hat z
$$

If you orient from $\vec P$ looking at the origin, then $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ will appear perpendicular.  There are a range of possible projections, corresponding to different values of $\phi$.